# Draw Renderable Shape on 3D Model using Sceneform Android

Tags: android, android-studio, 3d, arcore, sceneform

I am using [SceneForm Android SDK](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk) to render 3D Model in Android APP.

To display the 3D Model I am using this code below which also supports Rotating and Zooming feature in 3D Model

```
 private fun renderLocalObject(position: Int) {

    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(appCompatActivity, Uri.parse(models.get(position)))
            .setRegistryId(models.get(position))
            .build()
            .thenAccept { modelRenderable: ModelRenderable ->
                addNodeToScene(modelRenderable)
            }
            .exceptionally { throwable: Throwable? ->
                var message: String?
                message = if (throwable is CompletionException) {
                    Logger.DebugLog("ERROR LOADING 3D", throwable.message)
                    "Internet is not working"
                } else {
                    Logger.DebugLog("ERROR LOADING 3D", "FAILED TO LOAD")
                    "Can't load Model"

                }
                null
            }
}

private fun addNodeToScene(model: ModelRenderable) {

    if (sceneView != null) {

        val transformationSystem = makeTransformationSystem()
        val dragTransformableNode = DragTransformableNode(5f, transformationSystem)
        dragTransformableNode.renderable = model
        sceneView!!.scene.addChild(dragTransformableNode)
        dragTransformableNode.select()


        sceneView!!.getScene()
                .addOnPeekTouchListener { hitTestResult: HitTestResult?, motionEvent: MotionEvent? ->
                    transformationSystem.onTouch(
                            hitTestResult,
                            motionEvent
                    )

                    when (motionEvent?.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->
                            if (hitTestResult != null) {
                                addDot(hitTestResult)
                            }

                    }


                }
    }
}
```

I want to draw a sphere renderable shape directly over the 3d model, but the Node is not getting stuck model.

Below is the required output

[image: Expected Output]

Below is the final output of my code

[image: Final Output]

This is my code for adding node

```
  private fun addDot(hitTestResult: HitTestResult){
    val color = Color(.8f, 0f, 0f)
    MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(appCompatActivity, color)
            .thenAccept { material->
                // The sphere is in local coordinate space, so make the center 0,0,0
                val sphere = ShapeFactory.makeSphere(0.05f, Vector3.zero(),
                        material)
                val indicatorModel = Node()
                indicatorModel.setParent(hitTestResult.node)
                indicatorModel.worldPosition = hitTestResult.point
              //  indicatorModel.localPosition = Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f)
                indicatorModel.renderable = sphere
               // sceneView!!.getScene().addChild(indicatorModel)


            }
}
```

Is there any way to draw shape directly over the 3d model.

Comment: any updates to this answer?

Comment: no @DIRTYDAVE do you have any?